How to use relative paths in SCSS URLs which work for Angular application and karma builds
I've migrated a project to Angular 18 using @angular-devkit/build-angular:application as builder. During the migration process all relative paths in SCSS image URLs have been changed from "~/src/assets/images/..." (webpack style notation) to "assets/images/...". After successful application build everything worked as expected. However, if I attempt to run my karma/jasmine tests (karma builder obviously uses webpack instead of esbuild), I get the following error while building
file.scss?ngResource - Error: Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
myProj/src/app/xxx/file.scss:72:4: Can't resolve './assets/images/btn-left-menu.png' in 'myProj/src/app/xxx'
If I change all URLs back to webpack style paths, karma builds, loads and executes tests but then application build fails. Is it possible to use relative URLs in a way so they work in both build environments other than switching back to webpack builder for application also?
Tried to use proxies settings in karma.config.js as well as alternative ways to write relative URLs as in "../../assets/images/...", "./assets/images/...". Absolute paths i,e, "/assets/images/..." work but then I cannot use subdomains.

Update 2024-08-30
It turns out that this error (for us at least) is not consistent. After working for a while with the below fix, it began to fail again, prompting us to change to basePath: 'src/' which surprisingly worked (over several tries, 'src/' worked and 'src' didn't.)
Then after working for a while, it began to fail yet again!  We resorted to simply requeuing builds, because it turned into a complete coin flip if it would work or not.
Most recently we simply removed all styles and assets from the test builder:
// angular.json
"architect": {
  // ...
  "test": {
    "options": {
      "styles": [],
      "assets": [],
    }
  }
}

which repeatably removed the errors (for now).
We also added karma-esbuild to karma.conf.js:
plugins: [
  // ...
  require('karma-esbuild')
],
preprocessors: {
  '**/*.ts': ['esbuild'],
  '**/*.js': ['esbuild'],
}

This almost certainly had no impact on the problem (since it's presumably still using postcss-loader), but we did it at the same time.
I honestly don't even have confidence that that's truly using esbuild instead of webpack, because the build systems are so opaque, but I'm not debugging all that for a dead test runner.

Original Answer
I had this exact problem and just got bit by this updating to Angular 18, and after a very frustrating search and much trial and error (and swearing,) I found a solution!
angular.json:
//...
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            // Added the assets folder as an external dependency
            "externalDependencies": ["assets/*"],  // <-- 
            //...

karma.conf.js:
    //...
    // Set base path so relative paths are relative to this
    basePath: 'src',
    //...

And of course the url changes you already made:
    // src: url(~src/assets/path/to/file);
    src: url(assets/path/to/file);

The tradeoff is that ng build no longer validates that the file is actually present and named correctly, since it's marked as an external dependency now. Fortunately, this is mitigated by the webpack build from ng test still failing.

I tried this and it's not working for me. I used ng generate config karma to create the karma.config.js and then replaced the basePath: 'src', but I get the same error as before. url(assets/lockup_angular.svg) -> Can't resolve './assets/lockup_angular.svg'

It didn't work for us either after long, so we tried a couple things and ended up settling on a different answer that's working so far, knock on wood.  I just updated the answer (thank you for the reminder!)
